# I am trying to match exactly 6 numbers with Regex and \b as well as ^ and $ are not working

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the following regular expressions exactly

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{6}
```

So `12-34-56` or `123456` should return `true`, any other format should not.

I have tried `^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{6}$` as well as `\b\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{6}\b` however the test `12-34-5613216514` also matches with both.

Can you guys please help me figure out why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course after hours of trying to figure out where I went wrong, as soon as I ask the question I see the problem. Should have been doing

```
\b\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b|\b\d{6}\b
```

or

```
^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$|^\d{6}$
```

Comment: another way is use a group `^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{6})$` or non-capturing group `'^(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{6})$'`